# How to correctly live-reload new data from database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having a table on my website which is supposed to add a new row as soon as there is a new entry in my DB. 
Therefore I'm calling a PHP File via ajax to check the last entry in the DB - I do this every 3 seconds.

It worked quite well but now I realized my Website never finishes loading, it keeps on reloading the functions.php in which I have the whole process stored.

This can't be the way it's supposed to be done, can somebody enlighten me? :)

Here is some of my Code:

functions.php

```
function getBets(){

    require_once("mysql_con.php");

    $mysql_query = "SELECT id, time FROM access_log ORDER BY id DESC;";
    $result = $mysqli->query($mysql_query);
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    $liveData = [$row["id"],$row["time"]];

    echo json_encode($liveData);
}
```

events.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /**
     *  Live-Reload Live-Bets
     */

    refreshTable();
});
```

functions.js

```
function refreshTable(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "../php/functions.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {execute: "getBets"},
        success:function(data) {

            if(document.getElementById('table-bet-id').innerHTML != data[0]){
                $('#betFeed')[0].innerHTML = "<tr><td id = 'table-bet-id'>"+ data[0] +"</td><td>"+ data[1] +"</td><td>"+ data[2] +"</td><td>"+ data[3] +"</td></tr>" + $('#betFeed')[0].innerHTML;
            }
        }
    });
    setTimeout(refreshTable, 3000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: is the file this code is in 'functions.php' ?

Comment: *"I'm having a table on my website which is supposed to add a new row as soon as there is a new entry in my DB."* - I for one don't understand this line and the whole question really.

Comment: *"It worked quite well but now I realized my Website never finishes loading* - `setTimeout(refreshTable, 3000);` that's what it does, you code it. --- *"it keeps on reloading the functions.php in which I have the whole process stored"* - as in what, a stored procedure?

Comment: This is going to cause headaches for you. You're fetching **all** of the data on every single refresh. If you want to do this, you're better to look at WebSockets/etc to run a push instead of poll setup.

Comment: @Darren Have you got a few pointers regarding the Websocket part you're talking about? :)

Comment: @ShivaHaze Sure do mate, You're best to look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)/[Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/push) and [**This is a good example to follow the client/server method**](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html) :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you dont like the script to load all the "functions.php" file , why don't you just store your "getBets" function in another file ? 
because , you can't call only a part of a php file (unlike Xml for example )

Comment: In what other file tho, I have the getBets function in my functions.php already, it's where I collaborate all my php-functions :)